# Records are not getting deleted using <autocommit> feature in cloudsolrclient

Tags: solr

I am seeing strange behavior with the solar  feature.
SolrConfig.xml configurations are same in my local and stage instance.

```
<autoCommit>
      <maxTime>${solr.autoCommit.maxTime:5000}</maxTime>
      <openSearcher>false</openSearcher>
</autoCommit>

<autoSoftCommit>
      <maxTime>${solr.autoSoftCommit.maxTime:-1}</maxTime>
 </autoSoftCommit>
```

In my local setup I am using the below code

```
String urlString = "http://localhost:8983/solr/usersession"; 
 SolrClient Solr = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlString).build(); 
List<SolrInputDocument> doclist = new ArrayList<>();
        
          for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
              SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument(); 
          doc.addField("id", "test"+i); 
          doc.addField("cecid", "test"+i); 
          doc.addField("name","34"+i); 
          doc.addField("time_to_live_s", "+30000SECONDS"); 
          doclist.add(doc);
                
          }
          
          Solr.add(doclist);
```

Auto commit behaviour is working as expected. After 5 seconds i am seeing the records in solr admin UI after 5 seconds.

But in stage we are using CloudSolrclient with zookeeper setup but records are not seen in solr admin UI after 5 seconds. I am not sure why auto-commit feature is not working in stage server.
Can anyone let me know what can be the reason for this inconsistent behaviour with the same configuration settings.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the `${solr.autoSoftCommit.maxTime}` variable ist not set and -1 indicates no autoSoftCommit.

Try to set the fields directly in the `solrconfig.xml` and build the index again.

```xml
<!-- Example Config -->

<autoSoftCommit>
    <maxTime>1000</maxTime>
</autoSoftCommit>
```

Since Solr writes docs at startup you just could restart your Solr Server to quick check if the `${solr.autoSoftCommit.maxTime}` is the problem. After restart your documents should be available for search.